Extract request body from org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.Request
I am working with Spring Cloud Loadbalancer. I am sending my requests to my gateway using a request body, say:
{
    "id": "0000-1111"
}

I need to extract the id to do processing before I forward to request to my services. The requests are being forwarded to the services just fine, but I'm having trouble extracting the id in the gateway.
I tried logging the request.getContext() and the following was logged:
Request: [DefaultRequest@2823622f context = [RequestDataContext@eec4d12 clientRequest = [RequestData@593a40cd httpMethod = POST, url = http://localhost:8072/demo-endpoint, headers = map['Content-Type' -> list['application/json'], 'User-Agent' -> list['PostmanRuntime/7.37.3'], 'Accept' -> list['*/*'], 'Postman-Token' -> list['c7ff7f7d-0d4e-45a5-915a-34b390219cd0'], 'Host' -> list['localhost:8072'], 'Accept-Encoding' -> list['gzip, deflate, br'], 'Connection' -> list['keep-alive'], 'Content-Length' -> list['47']], cookies = map[[empty]]]]]

i.e. it is of RequestDataContext, I tried the following:
    private String extractId(Request request) {
        try {
            logger.info("Starting to extract Id from request: {}", request);

            if (!(request.getContext() instanceof RequestDataContext dataContext)) {
                logger.info("Request context is not RequestDataContext. Context: {}", request.getContext());
                return null;
            }
            
            RequestData clientRequest = dataContext.getClientRequest();
            logger.info("Client request: {}", clientRequest);

            // Log available data from RequestData
            logger.info("Headers: {}", clientRequest.getHeaders());

            // TODO: find the correct way to access the body i.e. content from the headers

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to extract meetingId", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Response<ServiceInstance>> choose(Request request) {
        String id = extractId(request);

        log.info("ID: {}", id)
        
        // other parts of code
    }

the logged headers correctly prints the content length (the length of my request body), but I am unable to extract the exact body?
UPDATE:
I wrote a request caching filter that enables me to store the request body to be used later and it works:
public Mono<Void> filter(
    ServerWebExchange exchange, 
    GatewayFilterChain chain
) {
    // Store exchange in attributes for later use
    exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchange.class.getName(), exchange);
    
    return DataBufferUtils.join(exchange.getRequest().getBody())
        .flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
            // Extract and cache request body
            byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
            dataBuffer.read(bytes);
            DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
            
            // Cache body as string in exchange attributes
            String bodyString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            exchange.getAttributes().put("cachedBody", bodyString);
            
            // Create decorated request that allows multiple reads
            ServerHttpRequest decoratedRequest = new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest()) {
                @Override
                @NonNull
                public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                    DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory();
                    return Flux.just(bufferFactory.wrap(bytes));
                }
            };
            
            // Continue with the filter chain using decorated request
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(decoratedRequest).build());
        })
        .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange));
}

and then wrote a config:
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(
        RouteLocatorBuilder builder, 
        RequestBodyCacheFilter requestBodyCacheFilter\
    ) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route(serviceId, r -> r
                .path(pathPattern)
                .filters(f -> f
                    .filter(requestBodyCacheFilter)
                    .stripPrefix(1)
                    .preserveHostHeader()
                )
                .uri(uri))
            .build();
    }


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
